# how to stop and restart web speech api correctly?

Tags: webkitspeechrecognition

Does it required to create new instance of SpeechRecognition after each speech?

```
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.start();
```

Or just stop() and call the start() func again?

```
recognition.stop();
recognition.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

Only 1 instance is necessary to interact with the SpeechRecognition object.

You can start the listener with [start()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/start).
You can stop the listener with [stop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/stop) or [abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/abort).

The abort() method slightly differs from the stop method:

> The abort() method of the Web Speech API stops the speech recognition
>   service from listening to incoming audio, and doesn't attempt to
>   return a SpeechRecognitionResult.

Here is the example straight from the docs:

```
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;

var diagnostic = document.querySelector('.output');
var bg = document.querySelector('html');

document.body.onclick = function() {
  recognition.start();
  console.log('Ready to receive a color command.');
}

abortBtn.onclick = function() {
  recognition.abort();
  console.log('Speech recognition aborted.');
}

recognition.onspeechend = function() {
  recognition.stop();
  console.log('Speech recognition has stopped.');
}
```

Find out more from the [SpeechRecognition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can pause and then continue the current instance by using:

```java
recognition.abort(); //and then followed by:
recognition.start();
```

if you want to re-start with new config, for example change the language:

```java
recognition.lang = 'id-ID'; //example to change the language
recognition.stop(); //stop recoginition

//try to give a bit delay and then start again with the same instance
setTimeout(function(){ recognition.start(); }, 400);
```

I have tested and it worked well.